# Looping through Table by Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I successfully able to loop through table by Angularjs to get values of determined scope named {{rec}} as following.

**HTML**

```
             <div id="AngularContainer" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
             <a data-ng-click='<%# "ShowFiles("+ Eval("FilesNames") + ")" %>' style="cursor: pointer">
                <table id="fils" style="display:none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>اسم الملف</td>
                            <td>مسمى الملف</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="rec in records">
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">{{rec}}</td>
               // values here display successfully when I press button #Second and because there is a scope here named {{rec}}
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
                        <input data-ng-model="naming" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
               // But here values not display when I press button #Second and because (data-ng-model="naming") that scope not related with {{rec}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                <input id="Second" data-ng-click="dothat()" class="sav" type="button" value="Save" />            
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            <div id="fnalmsg"></div>
          </div>
```

**Angularjs**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.ShowFiles = function (elm) {
            $scope.records = elm;
        };

        $scope.dothat = function () {
            var msg = document.getElementById("fnalmsg");

            var index = 0;
            $scope.records.forEach(function (rec, naming) {
                msg.innerHTML =
                msg.innerHTML + 'row #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(rec) + ' --- ' + naming + '<br />';
            });
        };
    });
  </script>
```

But I have a problem with looping through undefined scope named (data-ng-model="naming") dedicated to put values.

And my final printed view displayed something like this.

row #0: "WIN_20170226_191746.JPG" --- 0
row #1: "WIN_20170226_191848.JPG" --- 1
row #2: "WIN_20170226_191908.JPG" --- 2

the hypothetical view that should be displayed something like this.

row #0: "WIN_20170226_191746.JPG" --- "Friends"
row #1: "WIN_20170226_191848.JPG" --- "Animals"
row #2: "WIN_20170226_191908.JPG" --- "Cars"

In other words: How can I make (data-ng-model="naming") to display names like "Friends","Animals","Cars" as written in ng-model="naming" inputs rather than displaying unwanted values like 0,1,2 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an separate "naming" variable for each loop in the ng-repeat loop, you can have this data-ng-model="rec.naming" so each one in records list will also have naming being bind. In your controller file your function can be modified like this

```
 $scope.records.forEach(function (rec) {
            msg.innerHTML =
            msg.innerHTML + 'row #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(??) + ' --- ' + rec.naming+ '<br />';
        });
```

or else

you can use data-ng-model="naming[$index]" so that you will be binding to a new list. In the js file you can have naming[index].

I think later seems better solution for me. But in most cases the first approach will suit, but in your example you might go with 2nd approach. Let me know if you like any one of this approaches or if you find any better approach. Thank you

Comment: naming not belong to rec. so rec just simple json consisted from just one column with no name. so I cant do like this "rec.naming", In the same time I know that repeated scope naming returns array of values so if there is any way to return these values by index that would solcve my problem. I think about some thing like this in dothat function (naming[index++] rather than naming) but I can't fix that solution yet.

Comment: I think I dont clearly understand why the 2nd approach doesn't work for you.

Comment: Actually data-ng-model="naming[$index]" gives me result like this (row #0: "~\\191746.JPG" --- undefined) so it returns "undefined".

Comment: You did exactly same as the 2nd approach listed above.

Comment: Thank you so much bro @anveshtummala

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for this by add new scope array like this $scope.fileNames = [];

And replace input model with data-ng-model="fileNames[$index]"

Then retrieving its values by index like this $scope.fileNames[index]

So all code would be like : https://jsfiddle.net/medoo/wgc1my7d/3/

**HTML**

```
 <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="oneFile in ShowFiles">
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">{{oneFile}}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
                    <input data-ng-model="fileNames[$index]" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="save" data-ng-click="save()" type="button" value="Save" />
        <div id="msg"></div>
    </div>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
<script>
  var arr = ["~\\191746.JPG", "~\\191848.JPG", "~\\191908.JPG"];
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
     $scope.ShowFiles = arr;
      $scope.fileNames = [];

      $scope.save = function () {
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    $scope.ShowFiles.forEach(function (oneFile, index) {
        msg.innerHTML =
        msg.innerHTML + 'row #' + (index + 1) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(oneFile) + ' --- ' + $scope.fileNames[index] + '<br />';
    });
};
}); 
</script>
```